# JW Player Image not showing up within jQuery Cycle plugin - IE Only

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cycle, jwplayer

I've got a video embedded in a slideshow using JW Player & jQuery Cycle.  The preview image assigned to JW Player does not appear in IE (both 7 and 8) for some reason.  All other browsers show the preview image fine, and I have other videos that aren't in a cycle that IE shows the image correctly.

If I load that slide as the first slide, it shows up, but if its hidden and then "cycles" in later, the preview image is not there.  Is there any way I can:

A) Make IE keep the preview image always

B) Force JW Player to re-draw the preview image (I can hook into when the slide is shown in the cycle plugin, but I don't see an option to set or redraw the image in either JW Player's JS API or Flash API)  jwplayer('myVideo').redraw() causes lots more issues.

C) Any other ideas?

Here's a code sample, this has jQuery cycle bound to it:

```
        <ol id="slides">
            <li>Slide 1</li>
            <li>Slide 2</li>
            <li>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jwplayer/swfobject.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
                <div id="videoSpace">Sorry, your browser does not support this video.</div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    jwplayer('videoSpace').setup({
                        flashplayer: '/lib/jwplayer/player.swf',
                        file: 'my-video-file.mov',
                        image: 'my-image-preview.jpg',
                        height: 348,
                        width: 620,
                        events: {
                            onPlay: function() {
                                $('#slides').cycle('pause');
                            },
                            onComplete: function() {
                                $('#slides').cycle('resume');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                </script>
            </li>
        </ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved a similar problem for me...

http://blog.evansamek.com/2011/06/22/jwplayer-internet-explorer-jquery-bug-fix/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.